# Ajax update target id, but not action link

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery

So I used this before, but this is a link, with that behaviour once the link is clicked

```
    Ajax.ActionLink("XXX", "UpdateGridView", new {  }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "configs"})
);
```

What I want is a function in JS doing the same, calling an `Action` and given a `UpdateTargetId`, it will re render that partial view with that `Action`.

Is it possible?

Thank you

EDIT:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "AddUpdateConfigs",
            data: ({id: @Model.QueueMonitorConfigurationsID, pathType: $('#ddlConfigTypeName').val(), threshold:$('#ddlThreshold').val(), valueType:$('#ddlValueTypeName').val(), location: $('#txtbLocation').val(), limit: $('#txtbLimit').val(), config: $('#NewOrUpdate').val() }),
            dataType: 'application/json',
            statusCode: {
                404: function(){
                    alert("Data is duplicated");
                },
                405:function(){
                    alert("Location Path is not correct");
                },
                406: function(){
                    alert("Location Path has to be UNC path");
                },
                407: function(error){
                    alert(error);
                },
                410:function(result){
                    alert("Item added correctly");
                    $('#gridView').load('gvConfigurations');
                },
                411:function(result){
                    alert("Item updated correctly");
                }
            }
        });
```

So my code works, but when my Action returns with code 410, I want to call that `Action` and update the gridView `gvConfigurations`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/SomeController/UpdateGridView',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(result) {
        $('#configs').html(result);
    }
});
```

or the [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) equivalent:

```
$.get('/SomeController/UpdateGridView', function(result) {
    $('#configs').html(result);
});
```

or the even shorter equivalent using the [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
$('#configs').load('/SomeController/UpdateGridView');
```

Those 3 jQuery snippets all do the same: they send an AJAX request to `/SomeController/UpdateGridView` and update the DOM element with `id="configs"` with the returned partial result from this AJAX call.

Comment: Inspect your javascript code in your javascript debugging tool. You will be able to see the AJAX requests and what does the server respond. You will also be able to see potential errors with your code. So go ahead, launch FireBug or whatever javascript debugging tool you are using and start debugging. I gave you the correct jQuery functions you need to use. Now debug to understand why your code is not working. I cannot help any further with this. Maybe you provided a wrong url to your AJAX call here: `$('#gridView').load('gvConfigurations');` and the server simply returned `404 Not Found`.